# how to install amd raedon graphic card in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, graphics

I want to know whether ubuntu comes with preinstalled graphic drivers like windows 8?
or we have to manually download and install them. I just installed ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop. I installed steam and dota 2 but graphics are very bad. I have windows 8 also. in that it runs very fine - here is my driver information

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] [1002:6841] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device [104d:90ac]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at c4040000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks/Whistler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6000 Series] [1002:aa90]
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device [104d:90ac]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
```

My system information is showing like this for graphic card when u go into system settings and choose "details"

- memory 3.8gb
- processor intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
- graphcs Gallium 0.4 on AMD TURKS
- os type 64-bit
  = disk 110gb

Do I need to install AMD Radeon drivers into it or is it already installed?
If it is already installed, then why does Dota 2 is running without using my graphic card, because textures, lightening and everything is real bad. O have been playng games for more than 5 years so I know about graphics, but I played them on windows till now. I m totally new to Ubuntu or Linux. please help what is wrong here? Or do i have to set any launch options for Dota 2 to run properly?

when going into system settings, software and updates, addtitional drivers it is showing the following:

```
-advanced micro devices, inc. [amd/ati]: thames[raedon 7550m/7570m/7650m]
 this device is using the recommended driver.
 --using x.org x server - amd/ati display driver wrapper fromxserver-sorg
 --using video driver for the amd graphcs accelerators from fglrx (propreitary)
 --using video driver for the amd graphcs accelerators from fglrx-updates
```

in the above three options 1st one is selected. what to do?

Comment: Go to `System Settings` -> `Software and Updates` -> `Additional Drivers` and check whether any proprietary drivers are available.

Comment: @RohithMadhavan ya some driver are available. i have edited the question, plz check

Comment: @RohithMadhavan ya some drivers are available. i have edited the question, plz check

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install additional drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: this may break your computer. Make sure you have important things backed up, and a ubuntu usb on hand.

So what you're asking is how to install the drivers. You're at the right settings. Just select one of the two (fglrx) and let it run through its little loading thing. If it works, it might perform better for you. If not, it might break everything, and fail to load properly when you turn your computer on. In that case, boot from USB, install & select to keep your files, and everything *should* be alright. If not, you made a backup. Right?

Comment: even f u said this, but still u didnt said anything about fixing the problem. because i choose the other option and tried but the result was same